# How to redirect to special page when user is not in database in Yesod/Haskell

Tags: haskell, redirect, authorization, yesod

So, I really like the Yesod authentication options, since it means I don't have to manage securely storing passwords and hashes and such.

What I'm wondering is, how do I detect if someone is logging in for the first time, and then redirect them to a "Create an account" page so that they can link their credentials to the account for my web app (username, profile picture, etc.)

Right now, it's easy to detect whether the user is in my database. The part that's giving me trouble is figuring out how to do the redirect. Ideally, I want a flow like this

```
user tries to access page FOO requiring login
if they are logged in
    they go to FOO
if they are not logged in
    they log in with credentials
    if the credentials are in the database
        they go to FOO
    if the credentials are not in the database
        they get redirected to CreateProfile
        when the submit CreateProfile, they are redirected to FOO
```

Right now, I've set the `loginDest` to redirect them to a "check if in database" page, which then either redirects home or prompts them to create a profile. The problem with this is that the check only occurs if they go to `AuthR LoginR`. It does not occur if they go to a page which uses `requireAuth`.

I could do a check every time they go to a require page, but that would be a lot of code reuse, and seems ugly and non-modular.

Another potential solution is to redirect during getAuthId, but I have no idea how to do that, since it has type `Handler credentials`, not `Html`.

I'm open to suggestions about what is possible, and what is the best practice.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this what `isAuthorized` is for? You can view an example in [the yesod cook book](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/authentication-and-authorization) under "Authorization". The relevant part being,

```
-- route name, then a boolean indicating if it's a write request
isAuthorized HomeR True = isAdmin
isAuthorized AdminR _ = isAdmin

-- anyone can access other pages
isAuthorized _ _ = return Authorized
```

where instead of the `isAdmin` function, you'd simply check if they are logged in or not, and redirect them to the login page by returning `AuthenticationRequired` if they aren't.

EDIT: You mentioned something about checking if they are a "new" user. You should be able to do this in the function where you check if they are logged in. If you want to catch this for **all** pages, you could use `isAuthorized _ _` and run the function there.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure I have followed your question because your first paragraph just asks for detecting new users but later on you ask about `requireAuth` which you may be doing on all users not just new users. Anyways, assuming it is just for new users, I do something like this:

```
getMyLoginR :: Handler Html
getMyLoginR = do
   ur <- getUserRecord -- this is your check in the DB function 
                       -- (you will have to write it)
   if (isNothing ur)
     then do
       setMessage "Please set your preference"
       redirect PrefHandlerR  -- this is where you put your form asking for details
   else do
       redirect OtherHandlerR
```

Comment: No, that's not quite right. I know how to write a redirection page like that. My problem is, I want the user to be redirected to this page whenever they go to a page that requires login, i.e. when a handler calls `requireAuth`. This works great if the user goes to getMyLoginR, but it doesn't work if they go to another page requiring auth. I want to know how to make all authentication go through a check like this, so a user can't log in without being checked if they're a new user, and redirected if they are.

Comment: You can write a wrapper around `requireAuth` using `maybeAuth` (which will not redirect automatically) and then you can use that wrapper everywhere instead of requireAuth. 

Btw, in the above example, getMyLoginR is the login destination so you can track new users there. Of course, if someone signs in and then decides to skip that page but manually enter another url, that check will not happen. If that's the level of checking you need, you will have to create your own wrapper like I mentioned above

Comment: Ecognium: that was my plan too, but you can just over-ride maybeAuth now.  You can put redirects in it, and let requireAuth handle the redirect to login-page case.